How to 'git clone' a previous version of pytorch
How to 'git clone' the previous version of pytorch(without using conda)
I cloned the latest version 2.3.1 of pytorch locally using "git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git" in ubuntu, but I couldn't get around the sleef.h problem during compilation, so I wanted to try the previous version of pytorch. but I don't know how to clone it (without using conda)

Seems to be. Thank you.
